# Transfer data between hadoop clusters

Tags: hadoop

I would like to transfer data between 2 hadoop clusters located on different servers.

Source:
hadoop version
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.1

Destination:
hadoop version
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.1

I have a directory in source as:

hadoop fs -ls /bid_data/foo

I have a directory in destination as:

hadoop fs -ls /bid_data

I want to copy the /bid_data/foo directory and its content inside /bid_data in another cluster

Thank you,
Rio

=

updated:

Below is the error message I get when I use below command: Is it a firewall issue? The destination cluster is not open to the world which means I need VPN to access the destination cluster outside the local area network.

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/bid_data/foo hdfs://nn2:8020/bid_data




java.io.IOException: Copied: 0 Skipped: 0 Failed: 1
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.close(DistCp.java:582)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

=

```
yFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:314)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by:     org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=rio, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/rio/test":rio:warehouse:-rw-rw-rw-
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:177)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4716)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4698)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkTraverse(FSNamesystem.java:4677)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:2934)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:673)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:646)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:45002)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1701)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1697)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1695)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1231)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:629)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1545)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop provides an option to transfer data from one cluster to another. Its Distcp

The command for the same is

```
     hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/bid_data/foo hdfs://nn2:8020/bid_data
```

For more details refer :

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/distcp.html

Comment: Do I need to enter password? Is it "hadoop distcp hftp://nn1:50070/bid_data/foo hdfs://nn2:8020/bid_data". When do we use hftp?

Comment: no need of password and HFTP . Just use as mentioned it should work out

Comment: Check for your premissions in the dest hdfs location. See whether it has write privileges, etc.